# Value swapping issue in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, model

I am getting a fatal issue on my Firebase while working on a food delivery app. When I am giving a value for address on an alert dialog, I see on my Firebase it stored in total amount field. Just can't figured it out how to solve it.

Here is my `Request.java` File

```
public class Request{
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String total;
    private List<Order>foods;

    public Request() {
    }

    public Request(String phone, String name, String address, String total, List<Order> foods) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.total = total;
        this.foods = foods;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<Order> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public void setFoods(List<Order> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Cart.java` file:

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    TextView txtTotalPrice;
    Button btnPlace;

    List<Order> cart=new ArrayList<>();
    CartAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        //Firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests=database.getReference("Requests");

        //Init
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.listCart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        txtTotalPrice=findViewById(R.id.total);
        btnPlace=findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);

        btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              showAlertDialog();

            }
        });

        LoadListFood();

    }

    private void showAlertDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("One more step!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address :");



        final EditText edtAddress=new EditText(Cart.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );


        edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(edtAddress);  //Add edit text to alert dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Create new request

                Request request=new Request(

                        Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                        Common.currentUser.getName(),
                        txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                        edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                        cart

                );


                //Submit to Firebase
                //We will using System.currentMili to key

                requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                        .setValue(request);


                //Delete cart
                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();

                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you. Order placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void LoadListFood() {
        cart=new Database(this).getCarts();
        adapter=new CartAdapter(cart,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //Calculate total price

        int total=0;
        for (Order order:cart)
            total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));

        Locale locale=new Locale("en","US");
        NumberFormat fmt=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

    }
}
```

Here is my `FoodDetail.java`:

```
public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
    ImageView food_image;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    FloatingActionButton btnCart;
    ElegantNumberButton numberButton;


    String foodId="";
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foods;
    Food currentfood;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

        //Firebase

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foods=database.getReference("Foods");


        //Init View

        numberButton=findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        btnCart=findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

        btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                        foodId,
                        currentfood.getName(),
                        numberButton.getNumber(),
                        currentfood.getPrice(),
                        currentfood.getDiscountmenuId()

                ));

                Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        food_description=findViewById(R.id.food_description);
        food_name=findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        food_price=findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        food_image=findViewById(R.id.img_food);

        collapsingToolbarLayout=findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapseAppbar);

        //get Food Id from intent

        if (getIntent()!=null)
        foodId=getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");

        if (foodId != null && !foodId.isEmpty()){
            getDetailFood(foodId);
        }





    }

    private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {

        foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentfood=dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);


                //set Image

                Picasso.get().load(currentfood.getImage()).into(food_image);

                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(currentfood.getName());
                food_price.setText(currentfood.getPrice());
                food_name.setText(currentfood.getName());
                food_description.setText(currentfood.getDescription());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

When entered address It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote the data in your Model Class is wrong.

Please check the model properly :

```
Request request=new Request(
    Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
    Common.currentUser.getName(),
    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
    edtAddress.getText().toString(),
    cart
);
```

The location of Total price is in 4th position and address at 3 rd position in model class. while you submitting to the firebase you passed it in wrong order.

Change your model data to this :

```
Request request=new Request(
    Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
    Common.currentUser.getName(),
    edtAddress.getText().toString(),
    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
    cart
);
```